# Data Import via Json file in GO not as expected - fmt.Println only gives cryptic output back to prompt

Tags: json, go, variables, output

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/peterbourgon/ff"
)

var (
    compartmentOCID,
    bucketName,
    namespace *string
)

func main() {
    // Load config from JSON file
    compartmentOCID, bucketName, namespace := loadConfig()

    fmt.Println("Compartment OCID:", compartmentOCID)
    fmt.Println("Object Storage bucket name:", bucketName)
    fmt.Println("Object Storage namespace:", namespace)
}

// Load config
func loadConfig() (compartmentOCID *string, bucketName *string, namespace *string) {

    // Load creds from JSON into vars
    fs := flag.NewFlagSet("config", flag.ExitOnError)

    compartmentOCID = fs.String("compartment-ocid", "", "Compartment OCID")
    bucketName = fs.String("bucket", "", "Object Storage bucket name")
    namespace = fs.String("namespace", "", "Object Storage namespace")

    //  consumerKey = fs.String("consumerKey", "", "Twitter Consumer API key")
    //  consumerSecret = fs.String("consumerSecret", "", "Twitter Consumer API secret")

    //  accessToken = fs.String("accessToken", "", "Twitter Access Token")
    //  accessTokenSecret = fs.String("accessTokenSecret", "", "Twitter Access Token Secret")

    // senderEmail = fs.String("senderEmail", "", "Sender email")
    // recipientEmail = fs.String("recipientEmail", "", "Recipient email")

    //  ff.Parse(fs, nil, ff.WithConfigFile("config.json"), ff.WithConfigFileParser(ff.JSONParser))

    ff.Parse(fs, []string{},
        ff.WithConfigFile("config.json"),
        ff.WithConfigFileParser(ff.JSONParser))

    return compartmentOCID, bucketName, namespace
}
```

I am new to GO and playing around a bit. Not sure what I might miss, but I do only receive the following output:

> Compartment OCID: 0x1400008e040
> Object Storage bucket name: 0x1400008e050
> Object Storage namespace: 0x1400008e060

That's what is in the json:

> "bucket": "twitter-to-email",
> "compartment-ocid": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaa4gmjp4otjth423bk5aqnynhbhvpdok3a5ka4dtmcgytsciqsw3xq",
> "namespace": "frvhi6pjrbat",

Answer (score 0):

The function `loadConfig` returns pointers to strings.  The pointers are printed as memory addresses.

To get your expected result, change the function to return strings.

```
func loadConfig() (compartmentOCID string, bucketName string, namespace string) {
   ... other code as is
   return *compartmentOCID, *bucketName, *namespace
}
```

The changes are:

- Change return types from `*string` to `string`.
- Dereference the string pointers in the return statement.

---

The program does not use the package level variables compartmentOCID, bucketName and namespace.  Reduce confusion by deleting this declaration of the variables:

```
var (
    compartmentOCID,
    bucketName,
    namespace *string
)
```

Comment: Tried to implement as you advised, but then I receive the following error:      

`cannot use fs.String("compartment-ocid", "", "Compartment OCID") (value of type *string) as string value in assignment`